# accessing parent object on sencha

Tags: ajax, templates, mobile, extjs

I need to update sencha template when ajax call will be successful. The sample code is like below

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    tpl: '<p> {username} </p>',
    initComponent: function(){
        //Be sure to use the var keyword for planet earth, otherwise its declared as a global variable
        //var planetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 };
       //this.setHtml(this.getTpl().apply(planetEarth));
         Ext.Ajax.request( 
        {    
            waitMsg: 'Bitte warten...', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/casta/user/?format=json', 

            success:function(response,options){ 
                //var responseData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText); 
                  this.setHtml(this.getTpl().apply(response.responseText));
            }                       
        } 
        ); 
    }
});
```

Error console

```
this.getTpl is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

this.setHtml(this.getTpl().apply(response.responseText));
```

On `success` i need to update the template but the problem is that this.getTpl in undefined inside the inline function `success:function`. It is defined after `initcomponent`. I need to call that inside `success`. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really the parent. You can't travel up the dom to get it, but...

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    tpl: '<p> {username} </p>',
    initComponent: function(){
        //Be sure to use the var keyword for planet earth, otherwise its declared as a global variable
        //var planetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 };
       //this.setHtml(this.getTpl().apply(planetEarth));
       var me = this;
         Ext.Ajax.request( 
        {    
            waitMsg: 'Bitte warten...', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/casta/user/?format=json', 

            success:function(response,options){ 
                //var responseData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText); 
                  me.setHtml(me.getTpl().apply(response.responseText));
            }                       
        } 
        ); 
    }
});
```

Go read up on closures.